# How can I insert a Data inputted in a textbox from an onclick Alert event into DataBase

Tags: javascript, php, html

UI

[image]

code for the PHP Submit code meant to save the input data into the database,
i have tried my best but still seem not to crack this

```
if (isset($_POST['rjctrsn-data']) && !empty($_POST['rjctrsn-data'])) {
    $Note = $_POST['rjctrsn-data'];
    $whyreject = 'Rejection_Reason-'.$Note;
    $HclusterApprv = 3;

    $sql = "UPDATE requestitem SET requestitem_UsefulNote=:whyreject, requestitem_Hclusterapprv=:hclstapprv WHERE requestitem_id=:stffid  ";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':hclstapprv', $HclusterApprv);
    $query->bindParam(':whyreject', $whyreject);
    $query->bindParam(':stffid', $actid);
    if ($query->execute()) {
        $success = "Rejection Confirmed Successfully and Reason Sent.";
    } else {
        $error = "Sorry, Rejection Failed, Try again Later.";
    }
}
```

code for the cancel button, which runs the alert promt

````
```
 <input type="hidden" id="rjctrsn-data" href="" name="rejection_reason">    
<a type="submit" name="rejectionReason" onclick="document.getElementById('rjctrsn-data').value = prompt('Are you sure you want to Reject this Item ! :', 'Please State Reason for Rection');"
 value="" class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="0">
<span style="font-size:25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" style="color:red"></span>
</a>
```
````

JQUERY SCRIPT that helps the data to be to be pushed to the database

```
   <script>
function showRejectionReasonAlert() {
 var rejectionReason = prompt("Please enter the rejection reason:");
 if (rejectionReason != null) {
   document.getElementById("rjctrsn-data").value = rejectionReason;
   document.getElementById("FormId").submit();
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: use an `AJAX` request from the callback for the click handler

Comment: Where is`$actid` defined?

Comment: i defined stored it in a session and called it but it still didnt work, please assist me

Comment: Which piece is not working? Is it simply that the database does not get updated or does the form not get submitted?

Comment: the cancel reason the user inputs doesn't get saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

With no means of testing the final SQL update as per the question the best I can do is offer the following versions of Javascript - one that uses AJAX for a more refined user experience and the other more akin to the original and regular form submission.
In both cases below the value supplied in the `prompt` is submitted to the backend PHP script. This can be observed in the console if you run either snippet.

The PHP is untested but looks OK. You should verify where things break by using debug `echo` type statements throughout the php.

An example using AJAX

```js
document.querySelector('a[data-name="rejectionReason"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  
  const strprompt='Are you sure you want to Reject this Item ! :';
  
  let answer=prompt( strprompt );
  let form=document.querySelector('form#FormId');
  
  if( answer ){
    let fd=new FormData();
        fd.set('rjctrsn-data', answer );
        
    let config={
      method:'post',
      body:fd
    };
        
    fetch( form.action, config )
      .then( r=>r.text() )
      .then( alert )
      .catch( console.warn )
  }
});
```

```css
.glyphicon{ 
  display:block;
  width:350px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background:pink;
  border:1px solid black;
  color:red;
}
.glyphicon:after{
  content:"Click me baby one more time"
}
```

```html
<form method='post' id='FormId' action='/path/to/handler.php'>
  <a data-name="rejectionReason" data-id="0">
    <span style="font-size:25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" style="color:red"></span>
  </a>
</form>
```

---

An example using regular form submission

```js
document.querySelector('a[data-name="rejectionReason"]').addEventListener('click', e=>{
  const strprompt = 'Are you sure you want to Reject this Item ! :';
  
  let answer = prompt( strprompt );
  let form = e.target.closest('form');
  let input = form.querySelector('input[name="rjctrsn-data"]');
  
  if( answer ){
    input.value=answer;
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
.glyphicon{ 
  display:block; 
  width:350px; 
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background:yellow;
  border:1px solid blue;
  color:blue 
}
.glyphicon:after{
  content:"Come on Barbie, let's go Party!"
}
```

```html
<form method='post' id='FormId' action='/path/to/handler.php'>
  <a data-name="rejectionReason" data-id="0">
    <span style="font-size:25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" style="color:red"></span>
  </a>
  <input type='hidden' name='rjctrsn-data' />
</form>
```

And combine either with

```
<?php
    
    session_start();
    
    define('ACTID_SVAR_NAME','Name_of_Session_ACTID');
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['rjctrsn-data'] ) ){

        $whyreject = 'Rejection_Reason-'. $_POST['rjctrsn-data'];
        $HclusterApprv = 3;
        $actid = !empty( $_SESSION[ ACTID_SVAR_NAME ] ) ? $_SESSION[ ACTID_SVAR_NAME ] : false;
        
        if( $actid ){
            $args=array(
                ':hclstapprv'   =>  $HclusterApprv,
                ':whyreject'    =>  $whyreject,
                ':actid'        =>  $actid
            );
            
            $sql='UPDATE `requestitem` SET `requestitem_UsefulNote`=:whyreject, `requestitem_Hclusterapprv`=:hclstapprv WHERE `requestitem_id`=:actid';
            $stmt=$dbh->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->execute( $args );
            
            $status=$stmt->rowCount();
            exit( $status ? 'Rejection Confirmed Successfully and Reason Sent.' : 'Sorry, Rejection Failed, Try again Later.' );
        }
        
        exit('Unknown or empty "actid" value');
    }
?>
```